# Image capture in mobile web application?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

We are developing mobile web application(Android,Iphone) using MVC 3,HTML 5,Javascript,Jquery,Jquery mobile.I want to use the camera to capture images.In HTML 5 getUserMedia() is using for the image capture.But it is not supporting in many other browsers.So we cant use this option.Any other option is there to capture the images in mobile web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: This is correct..but most of the browsers this control is not supporting.

Comment: @kenna please read this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/ and youll get better understanding what will happened in case it is not supported

Comment: but getUserMedia() function is not supporting in android devices which mentioned in here http://mobilehtml5.org/

Comment: @kana - for some reson I dont trust the info on this site, I have tried my answer in ios6 all browsers and android 4.1+ and it is all working for me.

Comment: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/ with using this controls we are able to access the camera and can able to take images also..but front camera only working and the back camera is not working when the device is having camera with two sides.Please suggest me if any solution is there.

Comment: I am sorry mate, this is really too specific, you might find some directions here in this discussion: http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2011/10/19/new-opera-labs-release-with-getusermedia-and-opera-reader?startidx=50